# How to check instanceof class that is defined within a function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to export a class that is defined within a function. So, I tried declaring a class export like this:

```js
export declare class GameCameraComponent extends GameObject {
  isMainCamera: boolean;
}


export abstract class GameObject<T extends { new(...args: any[]): any; } = any> { }

// Used for my decorator
export function Camera(options?: CameraOptions) {
  return function (target: new () => object) {
    return class GameCameraComponent extends GameObject { 
      instance = new target();
      readonly isMainCamera; // Set in the constructor
    }
  }
}
```

No errors are created everything seems fine. Now I want to check somewhere else if the item is an instance of that exported definition like this:

```js
export class CameraService {
  constructor() {
    const cam = Engine.gameObjects.find(o => o instanceof GameCameraComponent && o.isMainCamera);
  }
}
```

Now at this point, I get the two following errors (I believe this is from webpack as there are no errors in the vscode editor):

```
export 'GameCameraComponent' (imported as 'GameCameraComponent') was not found in '../decorators' (possible exports: Camera, GameObject, ObjectChild, ObjectChildren, Path, Prefab)
```

Next, in the chrome console I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
```

How can I see if the item is an instanceof the inner function class?

Answer (score 0):

Instanceof validates if an object is created by a class. Only passing the same name in the return is not valid. The following though, is possible:

```
export class GameCameraComponent extends GameObject {
  isMainCamera: boolean;
}

export function Camera(options?: CameraOptions) {
  return function (target: new () => object) {
    return new GameCameraComponent()
  }
}

const myInstance = Camera()()

myInstance instanceOf GameCameraComponent // true
```

The return type now equals `instanceof` GameCameraComponent.

Comment: The actual class is in the function `return class GameCameraComponent extends GameObject`. I don't think changing the export would work

Comment: I saw that indeed, I've never seen such an approach, and I honestly think it is not possibly. If you use instanceof, the `GameCameraComponent` must be declared and be importable. So instead of return class GameCameraComponent, you should return `new GameCameraComponent()`. Else it will never be able to validate if it is an instanceof. I will update my answer

Comment: As this is a decorator, I don't believe you can return a `newable` in the function. But I am seeing what I can do based of your sugguestion.